# Node has no available volume zone in AWS EKS

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

Trying to create pod but getting following error:

0/3 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had no available volume zone.

I tried to attach more volume but still the error is same.

> Warning  FailedScheduling  2s (x14 over 42s)  default-scheduler  0/3 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had no available volume zone, 2 node(s) didn't have free ports for the requested pod ports.

Comment: Please update question with your pod/deployment  yaml file

Comment: I have the same problem. I have very similar setup in 2 accounts, one is OK but one gets this error (in my case: _0/2 nodes are available: 2 node(s) had no available volume zone_). See https://gist.github.com/holyjak/fc6e35a4228d348cf89eef5303473cab#file-eks-pod-no-avail-volume-zone-yml
Related: https://www.henryxieblogs.com/2019/04/error-no-available-volume-zone-in.html , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53854588/kubernetes-pod-pending-when-a-new-volume-is-attached-eks

Comment: BTW this is worth reading https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/ - in my case the problem seems to be some misconfiguration of volumes / volume creation.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the AWS EC2 Volume and [Kubernetes PersistentVolume (PV)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) state got somehow out of sync / corrupted. Kubernetes believed there was a bound PV while the EC2 Volume showed as "available", not mounted to a worker node.
*Update*: The volume was in a different avail. zone then either of the 2 EC2 nodes and thus could not be attached to them.

The solution was to delete all relevant resources - StatefulSet, [PVC (crucial!)](https://serverfault.com/questions/965535/kubectl-delete-pv-id-says-deleted-but-hangs-and-the-pv-still-exists-aws/965536#965536), PV. Then I was able to `apply` them again and Kubernetes succeeded in creating a new EC2 Volume and attaching it to the instance.

As you can see [in my configuration](https://gist.github.com/holyjak/fc6e35a4228d348cf89eef5303473cab#file-eks-pod-no-avail-volume-zone-yml), I have a StatefulSet with a "volumeClaimTemplate" (=> PersistentVolumeClaim, PVC) (and a [matching StorageClass definition](https://gist.github.com/holyjak/fc6e35a4228d348cf89eef5303473cab#file-storage-yml)) so Kubernetes should dynamically provision an EC2 Volume, attach it to a worker and expose it as a PersistentVolume.

See `kubectl get pvc`, `kubectl get pv` and in the AWS Console - EC2 - Volumes.

NOTE: "Bound" = the PV is [bound](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#binding) to the PVC.

Here is a description of a laborious way to *restore* a StatefulSet on AWS if you have a snapshot of the EBS volume (5/2018): https://medium.com/@joatmon08/kubernetes-statefulset-recovery-from-aws-snapshots-8a6159cda6f1